# Каждую форму обрабатывать отдельно serialize()

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, что вписать в приведенном ниже коде, чтобы каждая форма обрабатывалась отдельно.

А, то сериализится все в общем списке

```js
$(function() {
  var c = $(".sticker .one img").attr("src");
  var e = $(".sticker form input, .sticker form select");
  var b = $(".product-details-block form.property-form");
  e.on("input change", (function() {
    $(".sticker .one img.m").each(function() {
      var a = $(this);
      a.attr("src", c + "?type=" + a.attr("data-type") + "&" + $(".sticker form").serialize())
    });
    $(".sticker .one img.n").attr("src", c + "?" + $(".sticker form").serialize());
    e.each(function() {
      var a = $(this);
      var f = $(':input[name="' + a.attr("name") + '"]', b);
      if (!f.length) {
        return true
      }
      f.val(a.hasClass("form-value-text") ? $('>option[value="' + a.val() + '"]', a).text() : a.val())
    })
  })).first().triggerHandler("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticker">
  <div class="one">
    <!-- Форма 1 -->
    <img class="n" src="img/">
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" name="one">
    </form>
    <!-- Форма 2 -->
    <img class="n" src="img/">
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" name="two">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ты хотя бы выучил, что jquery пишется через `u` >_<

Comment: А есть ответ по теме?